# Не работает метод ImportReference - Mono.Cecil, Fody

Tags: c#, рефлексия, mono, aop

Использую [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody).

Немного контекста:
Вместо создания своего ткача я использую возможность создания in-solution ткача. (Прим. weaver = ткач (в переводе), следуя терминологии из описания Fody) То есть я создаю в одном решении два проекта - целевой и проект-ткач. Я хочу сделать shared-project ткача (вместо распространения через nuget), который будет реализовывать концепцию, схожую с PostSharp. Ну если я, конечно, не ошибся с тем, как это там работает, т.к. вникать в такой жадный проприетарный инструмент не захотелось. Принцип работы такой: создаем атрибуты-ткачи, которые отнаследованы от специальных классов, описанных в библиотеке AOPHelpers. Мой ткач ищет помеченные этим атрибутом классы, методы и тп. У каждого атрибута есть метод Execute, который с помощью позднего связывания выполняется моим проектом-ткачом.

Таким образом, мы имеем связку Mono.Cecil + System.Reflection. Чтобы не было конфликтов, при записи файла Mono.Cecil я вручную считываю байты сборки, и использую нужную перегрузку метода Assembly.Load.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема с методом ***ModuleDefinition.ImportReference***. Он вроде срабатывает, что-то возвращает (TypeReference), но вызов Resolve, чтобы получить TypeDefiniton молча выдает null:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я не знаю как это работает, но TypeReference возможно привести к TypeDefinition и в одном месте кода это срабатывает, но в моей проблемной строке нет (падает с каст-эксепшин). 
Кстати, отладчик не работает, кто знает, чем это можно компенсировать(кроме логирования...)?

[Ссылка](https://gitlab.com/Raevski/aspectprogramming.git) на клон проекта.

Comment: Нашел следующие ссылки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353245/method-import-using-mono-cecil. Я не уверен, но по идее там сказано так: импортировать типы из сборки n можно только через ModuleDefiniton сборки n. Как-то так. Но у меня загрузка сборки через Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("file")); - это нужно, т.к. просто Assembly.Load("filename"); блокирует файл сборки, и когда в конце Fody пытается записать изменения - ошибка. Я не знаю влияет ли это как-то на возможность импорта. К тому же, если следовать моей интерпретации того ответа, то вызов импорта я сделал из нуджного ModuleDef

Comment: К тому же в том вопросе есть исключение. А у меня его нет, а ресолвинг молча дает null. Открыл для себя документацию Mono.Cecil: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Resolving. Склоняюсь к тому, что причина именно в том, что позднее связывание с сборкой происходит не через Assembly.Load("file");. Я думаю, что нужно использовать System.Reflection исключительно для позднего связывания, а для анализа метаданных исключительно Mono.Cecil (Отказаться от ImportReference то есть.)

Comment: Хотя, это вынуждает на некоторых этапах использовать сопоставление имен поиска, в качестве замены ImportReference... А для Genericов именование по другому происходит... В общем очень жаль...